# Weighted Generalized linear model (GLM)

Tags: glm, weighted

I have data of diet composition (3 food types) of 6 species collected from 4 sites. The data is in terms of mean and standard deviation. Can I use generalized linear model to check if there is significant differences among the species and sites?

The data is as follows.

```
SD<-runif(72, 0.1, 2)
 N<-runif(72,1,6)
data <- data.frame(Species = c(rep("Sp1", 4), rep("Sp2", 4), rep("Sp3", 4), rep("Sp4", 4), rep("Sp5", 4), rep("Sp6", 4)),
                   Site = c(rep(c("Site1", "Site2", "Site3","Site4"), 6)),
                   Food_Type = rep(c("Type1", "Type2", "Type3"), 24),
                   Mean = rep(c(runif(3) / sum(random_numbers)),24),
                   SD = SD,
                   N=N)
```

I am thinking about using

```
data$Success <- round(data$Mean * data$N)
data$Trials <- data$N

model <- glm(cbind(Success, Trials - Success) ~ Species + Site + Food_Type, data = data, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

However, I am not sure how to incorporate the uncertainty (SD) into the model. Perhaps a weight term should be added? Any recommendation is welcome. Thank you!!!